# class_weigths in claserization in lib scikit, python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm new in scikit so this is a simple question

I have tryed to pass class_weigths param with dict type to claserization like sklearn.svm.SVC

Can someone give me example of correct param dict, I tryed to use `model.class_weight = dict(zero=100, one=1)` but in SVM it gives :

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('S32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

in other methods I got no effect :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure why you want to call the keys of the dictionary by strings. According to [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) and [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane_unbalanced.html) example, you want the keys to represent the indices of your classes. That is, you want them to be integers!

Taking from the example in the link above, they instantiate the SVM with the following weights (again, using integers to index the classes):

```
wclf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', class_weight={1: 10})
```

which, for your example, would require you to use

```
model.class_weight = {0:100, 1:1}
```

Comment: I used strings because I'm noob in python :)) Thanks for answer and link, I didn't find any examples.